# Create an identity matrix of densevectors as a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I need to find out how to create an identity matrix of `DenseVectors` of arbitrary size in Spark. I was trying to do something from the `mllib.linalg.distributed` module but to no avail. What I need is a dataframe with one column "features" which has `DenseVectors` as its rows where each row is the corresponding row in an identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple with `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed`:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import MatrixEntry, CoordinateMatrix
from pyspark import SparkContext

def identity(n: int, sc: SparkContext) -> CoordinateMatrix:
    return CoordinateMatrix(
        sc.range(n).map(lambda i: MatrixEntry(i, i, 1.0)), n, n)
```

Using `DataFrames` and `DenseVectors` doesn't make much sense. First of all `DataFrames` are not ordered and don't support algebraic operations. Moreover using `DenseVectors` will cause memory issues with matrices of any size, where using distributed data structures is justified.